# Semantic zoom in browser HTML5 (NOT win.js)

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-zoom

I am building a web SPA and I'd love to use semantic zoom. I rather not bother implementing it, so I was wondering if such a library has already been built (SO and googled showed only results concerning Win.Js).

Answer (score 0):

I found the following jQuery plugin library. while it is not in itself a semantic zoom library it can Aid you in creating semantic zoom.

http://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/

When you zoom on an element it adds the class  selectedZoomTarget you could use this in css to show/toggle more data inside your target.

The page doesn't show examples of nested zoom targets but you might be able to do it using jQuery click events.